# Application Sending Too Many SMS

Tags: android

I have developed an application for sending sms using the `SmsManager` class

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager .sendTextMessage("123456", null, "msg", null,null);
```

, after a while if i send messages one after another a dialog appears saying the application so and so is sending too many sms `Allow` or `Deny`, where as if i send messages using the native app such mesasge does not appear...Any thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just for security. You can really rack up someone's phone bill by sending truckloads of texts. So long as the user knows that's what you're doing, they'll press allow and your app will continue to swim along. In my opinion, opening the default messaging app is tacky unless you want the user to edit the message before you send it.

Comment: im not opening the default app, is there a way i can open it and not allow the user to edit the text? (i know how to send sms using intent, but dont know if it is possible to bar user from editing the text)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798657/send-sms-via-intent answers this question.