# Default Messenger app is not Opening

Tags: android, messenger

I am working on Messages and issue which i am facing here is default messenger app is not opening in **Lenovo K8 Note (7.1.1)** on tapping the button and this issue occurs only in this device.I analysed forums but i didnt get a proper solution.Suggest me how to resolve this issue.

```
 chat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              try {
        Intent sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sms.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        sms.putExtra("sms_body_popup",
                getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.custom_refer_message_chat)
                        + "\n" + str_url);
        startActivity(sms);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.no_default_apps),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is code . How you expecting a solution without any code ?

Comment: @ADM This is my piece of code

Comment: Try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798870/4168607)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, Can i expect some code snippet for your query.

Comment: @MaheskumarSubramani instead of "sms_body_popup" use "sms_body" it should work since just now i tested on Lenovo A7 and is working fine. Check at your end and if it works please accept this solution