# ActivityNotFoundException for sms intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

My sendSms function has try and catch blocks. `Try` block is default device sms application. `catch` block is other sms applications which set as current sms application for example Google SMS app.

Some phones(generally API version is 19) have this error when running this `sendSms` code.

**My error log:**

```
Exception android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=sms:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }
android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult (Instrumentation.java:1638)
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1430)
android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:1135)
android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:1117)
android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity (ContextWrapper.java:311)
android.view.View.performClick (View.java:4463)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:18794)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:808)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:103)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5299)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:825)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:641)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

**My code:**

```
private void sendSms(String phoneNumber){
   try {
    
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.inviteSms));
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        sendIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
        sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getContext().startActivity(sendIntent);
    
       } catch (Exception e) {
    
        String SMS_DEFAULT_APPLICATION = "sms_default_application";
    
        String defaultApplication = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), SMS_DEFAULT_APPLICATION);
        PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(defaultApplication);
    
        if (intent != null) {
    
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", phoneNumber, null));
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", getContext().getString(R.string.inviteSms));
        smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getContext().startActivity(smsIntent);
        }
       }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send SMS via intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798657/send-sms-via-intent)

Comment: no @NileshRathod it is different question, I already made your example answer

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079047/android-kitkat-4-4-hangouts-cannot-handle-sending-sms-intent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```java
     if (getDefaultSmsAppPackageName() != null) {
         Uri smsUri=  Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber);
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, smsUri);
         intent.putExtra("sms_body", "sms text");
         intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
         startActivity(intent);
     }

    public static String getDefaultSmsAppPackageName(@NonNull Context context) {
        String defaultSmsPackageName;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
            return defaultSmsPackageName;
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT).setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            if (resolveInfos != null && !resolveInfos.isEmpty())
                return resolveInfos.get(0).activityInfo.packageName;

        }
       return null;
    }
```

Comment: where can I use getDefaultSmsAppPackageName()? intent.setPackageName()?

Comment: Yup. but one more use in application. let suppose in your mobile have no any sms app. so you can check before perform  send message.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder("sms:" + mobilenumber);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
sendIntent.setData("");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

First time please remove setFlags and try my source.Also share your gradle file's source

Comment: uri is data,isn't it?

Comment: You can put your mobile numer for example ("sms:+123456796566) @propoLis