# What is the code to send SMS if there is no internet connection?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sms

I want to make an app to send some information to the company via email if I have internet connection as a user and I use email intent

```
String priceMassage = creatOrderSummery(price, hasWippedCream, hasChocolate, name);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: ")); // only email apps should handle this
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just Java order for " + name);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, priceMassage);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}

displayMessage(priceMassage);
```

but if I don't internet connection I want the information sent to company mobile number via SMS, how can I do it?

Comment: From when sms depends on internet connection ??

Comment: @Zainab you mean you want to check internet first if online send mail else send sms..if that what you want let me know so i post code for that..ok??

Comment: Please change your Title, it is irrelevant to what you explained in description.

Comment: Hi Zainab, If the below answers clarifies your doubt, can you please close this thread by accepting the answer.

Comment: @ALTegani yes that what I mean

Comment: @zainab check my answer...dont forget the permissions(internet,sms)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this code to check intenet connection..in main

```
TestInternet testInternet = new TestInternet();
        testInternet.execute();
```

out of main

```
class TestInternet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
        {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(4000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
            {
                if (!result)
                {
               // send sms
                else
                    {
                     //send mail     
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I created new class named it TestInternet and I coped the code you have putted it and in main I put the 2 line codes put it gave me error!!

Comment: use the class outside your main...and use these two lines to TestInternet testInternet = new TestInternet();
        testInternet.execute();   to execute it

Comment: insure your class out of main and you import what is ask for

Comment: I did it, but now how can I connect the code (checking internet connection) with submitOrder button it main class?

Comment: put the class out of oncreate method and use this TestInternet testInternet = new TestInternet(); testInternet.execute(); where you need to check internet for exmple onclick of button

Comment: @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
            {
                if (!result)
                {
               // send sms here
                else
                    {
                     //send mail  here   
                    }
            }

Comment: please check it here I didn't get your point https://gist.github.com/smart-princess/29fb2b093693dd119e6f0e49f9610c39

Comment: i commented there i modified it....put the sms code inside the if inside the onPostExecute @zainab...let me know its ok with you

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to send SMS.

1. **Using SmsManager API**

   `SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
   smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);`
2. **Using Built-in SMS application**

   `Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
   sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
   startActivity(sendIntent);`

Both need SEND_SMS permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

More details can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for internet connectivity first if present use email otherwise open the intent to send sms message.

for connectivity check see this helpful answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548926/4428159

For sending sms I'm assuming  you need to just open the sms app and send the message so have a look at this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798870/4428159

For this you don't need sms permission in your application.

```
public void sendSMS(View v) 
      { 
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:12346556"); 
         Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri); 
         it.putExtra("sms_body", "Here you can set the SMS text to be sent"); 
         startActivity(it); 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if the device is connected to the internet

you can check internet connection via `ConnectionManager` class.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected(); // return true if internet or otherwise flase

if (internet){
 // Email send code here
} else {
 // SMS send code here
}
```

this is the sample solution

Comment: I used it but it gave me error in (context) and (internet)

Comment: share code here you use it. context is the activity. instance of if (internet ) use if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())

Answer (score 0):

In order to send sms

In AndroidManifest.xml add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

public void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg) {
    try {      
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);    
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage().toString(),
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```